# Add extra column to anyelement type - querying across multiple schemas with extra information

Tags: postgresql, schema, multi-tenant

I'm trying to create a generic function which can be used to query across all of my schemas. I'm using schemas to separate my tenants, so they all have the structure.

I found Staab's post useful: https://dev.to/staab/how-to-query-multiple-schemas-with-postgresql-28kj but need to take it a step further and haven't been successful.

I want to include some extra info when querying across all my tenants so I know which schema the data comes from. I've created a db-fiddle to help illustrate my issue: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cDJchNWtjvHzwsyY3L6ZPd/4

The trouble comes when I try and extend anyelement to include an extra column.

I have tried returning a table with a schema name column type and then the anyelement type. This didn't work

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_union_with_schema_name(tbl anyelement)
RETURNS TABLE (
  S text,
  r anyelement
) AS 
$$
BEGIN
  return query execute string_agg(
    distinct format('select %L as S, %I.* from %I.%I', schema_name::text, pg_typeof(tbl)::text, schema_name, pg_typeof(tbl)::text, pg_typeof(tbl)::text), 
    ' union all '
  ) from public.schema_names where schema_name != 'public';
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Returns:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type int does not match expected type test in column 2.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.schema_union_with_schema_name(anyelement) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 42804
```

The query which is generated will run fine, so I am able to use the function to generate the union and then run the query separately.

edit: I found a better db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=88cfbd62c7da57dc2373bda87a0178bc

The idea is to be able to query across my schemas and return the schema name. If I use the same function but return the text of the query it is:

```
select 'schema1' as S, test.* from schema1.test 
union all
select 'schema2' as S, test.* from schema2.test
```

which returns:

```
s       id
schema1 1
schema1 2
schema2 3
schema2 4
```

Comment: If the parameter `tbl` is supposed to be a table name, then pass it as `text` - ideally schema and table name as two separate parameters. `anyelement` is the wrong type for this. Or pass a value of `regclass` which is the "generic" type for table names.

Comment: How would I define the return type with regclass? The postgres docs say to use anyelement for polymorphic functions. Here the return type is based on the input type so I don't think regclass would fit here. The schema names come from another table - they're not an input to the function. The idea of the function is to query across all of my schemas on a given table

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. How should the result look for some sample function arguments?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to make it more clear. I've also posted the link to a better fiddle, which shows the working queries